# How to get the ID of the most common FK in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

```
Table: Player
-----------------
| id |  gameId  |
-----------------
| 1  |    1     |
-----------------
| 2  |    1     |
-----------------
| 3  |    2     |
-----------------
| 4  |    1     |
-----------------

Table: Game
----------
| gameId |
----------
|   1    |
----------
|   2    |
----------
```

I want to get the game with the most players, in this case game 1. This is what I have tried, but with my query I get 2 columns: gi and counted. I want to get only gi

```
SELECT gi, MAX(counted) FROM
(
    SELECT gameId AS gi, COUNT(gameId) AS counted
    FROM player
    GROUP BY gameId
) AS countens;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
select `gameid`
from `player`
group by `gameid`
having count(*) = (
   select count(*)
   from `player`
   group by `gameid`
   order by count(*) desc
   limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one game, you can use:

```
SELECT gameId AS gi, COUNT(gameId) AS counted
FROM player
GROUP BY gameId
ORDER BY counted DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  this returns the highest scoring game.  If there are ties, an arbitrary tie value is chosen.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I got it!

```
SELECT gameId FROM(
   SELECT gameId, MAX(counted) FROM
   (
       SELECT gameId, COUNT(gameId) AS counted
       FROM player
       GROUP BY gameId
   ) AS countens
)AS gi;
```

Comment: This gets the highest `counted`, but the value returned for `gameId` is indeterminate. That is, there is no guarantee that the value returned will be for the game that has the most players. Databases other than MySQL would throw an error with this statement "non-aggregate in select list but not in group by". By default, a MySQL extension allows this query to run. We can get MySQL to also return an error, by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode.